# Change default regexp behavior in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Is there some global option available in Perl which specifies the default behavior regexp match behavior? Like ignore case by default even without `i` option match operator.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There's definitely a possible can of worms implicit in globally altering something that everyone _thinks_ they know how it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be looking for [`re` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html)

> ```
> use re '/ix';  
> "FOO" =~ / foo /; # /ix implied  
> no re '/x';  
> "FOO" =~ /foo/;   # just /i implied
> ```

Comment: Note that this is not global, but only applies to the current lexical scope. A global flag would be a bad idea, since modules (including things like `strict`) rely on case-sensitive matching.

Comment: There are more implications and specifics. (Example: `re /flag` overrides `locale` pragma and the 'unicode_strings' `feature` for regex -- which is all restored after `no re /flag`.)